# boost threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

So I'm modifying a code to be multithreaded, I have read several articles but have not found my answer, I have the Main, Class A, Class B, now I want to know if it's possible to program threads in class b so when when main calls class a this in turn calls class b and here the treads are created, not from the main from the subclasses. Thanks.

Main

```
fr.place_sequences_to_nodes(&sequences,&leaf_nodes,reference_alignment,data_type‌​); 
int count = 1; root->name_internal_nodes(&count); 
root->start_alignment(&mf); 
ss.str(string()); 
ss << "Time main::align: "<< double(clock()-t_start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<"\n";   
Log_output::write_out(ss.str(),"time");
```

Node

```
void align_sequences(Model_factory *mf) 
{ 
    if(leaf) return; 
    left_child->align_sequences(mf); 
    right_child->align_sequences(mf); 
    this->align_sequences_this_node(mf); 
}
```

Comment: You should post some of your code, it would help us give you a better answer.

Comment: You can edit your first post (with the question in it) to contain the code (copy and paste from your source), and it would be clearer.

Comment: So as you can see i have the main but this is not where the action happens, is in node so how do I create the threads from node that will just run for a short period and then return to main and continue, ok i see sure thing

Comment: Nevermind. I edited your post. In general you can use any start a thread which will run any function you like. You can use Boost, Apache Decaf, Intel Thread Building blocks for ease-of-use, but basically they all allow the same set of operations.

Comment: Thanks I'm using boost here it looks simpler, I just need a working example from a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are independent, regardless of which other thread creates them. They are all the same. Thread A can create thread B which creates thread C which creates thread D and all of them will be the same kind of thread.

You can create them from wherever you want, just follow the documentation and remember the caveats (such as using a scoped_ptr to an RAII thread object which goes out of scope, causing the object to crash).

Comment: @user1423656 starting at part 2 http://blog.emptycrate.com/taxonomy/term/31,33,38 that defines a decent starting point for you

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing class and thread here and maybe confusing yourself... You'll have a single execution thread if your current application is single threaded. You can create more threads, the instance of the class they're created from shouldn't really matter (apart from scoping of the instance, potentially letting thread references drop out of scope so they'd be uncontrollable). Without an example, I can't say much more.